# Customize the validation when user sign in in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a website that uses Devise for authentication.

While sign in if email and password both are empty it is giving me error

> Invalid email or password.

but I want to show different error messages for users for different cases:

For instance,
if email field is empty and the password is present then show

> Email can't be blank.

else if password field is empty and email is present than show

> Password can't be blank.

else password and email are unauthenticated than show

> invalid email or password

which currently working.

I don't want to remove `:validatable`  from my model.

I tired `validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true`

from  [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Use-a-custom-email-validator-with-Devise)

but when I sign up it shows 2 errors of

> Email can't be blank.

one error of Devise and the other for the model.

please tell me how to do this validation only for user sign-in.

Comment: You can override devise's session controller's create action and add some checks their?

Comment: @Navin thank you for your reply.. but what if i dont want to override session controller...??

Comment: you have check for email and password specifically whether they are present or not or invalid with different error messages that's why I suggest you to override session controller of devise.

Comment: Please look at this link https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Override-devise_error_messages!-for-views.   The devise wiki has a fairly large list of  How-To articles and that's where I would always start.

Comment: @jaydel thnx.. i already tired this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your devise session controller's create action.

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
  if user
    if user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password]) 
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      flash[:error] =  "Please enter the valid password."
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thnx bro.. i added this lines
 if params[:user][:email] == '' &&  params[:user][:password] == ''
      redirect_to login_path,:flash => { :error => "Email and password can't be blank" }
    elsif params[:user][:email] == ''
      redirect_to login_path,:flash => { :error => "Email can't be blank" }
    elsif params[:user][:password] == ''
      redirect_to login_path,:flash => { :error =>  "Password cant be blank" } 
    else
     super
    end
and its working fine.. i want ur suggestion. :)

Comment: okay great, you also have to handle case of correct email and password.If your issue is solved then please accept the answer.

Comment: i accepetd answer.,. happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Please prefer this
 [Link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise?view=asciicast)

If the user is signing in, you can edit all the error messages in devise.en.yml under `config/locales.`